# ASP.NET Menu Styling. Border on the bottom of the last element in the dynamic menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, menu

I have a basic ASP:Menu on my website.

What I am trying to do is add a 1px solid black border to the bottom of the final element in my drop down menus. CSS doesn't seem to do anything and I cant seem to find a control that can do it either.

Any help or information on this topic will be most appreciated.

So far I have added the menu onto the site. The CSS mainly changes the colors, fonts and :hover styles. As I said above when I add a border to the CSS nothing seems to happen? So I can only presume I'm missing some control?

HTML CODE

```
            <div id="navigation">
                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="nbottom"
                    DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="nbottomitem"
                    StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="ntop"> 
                </asp:Menu>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
            </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
#navigation {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #A9A9A9;
}
.ntop {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #A9A9A9;
}
.nbottom {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 360px;
}
.nbottom:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #4fd0f0;
}
.ntop:hover {
    color: #4fd0f0;
}
```

http://tinypic.com/r/mhfzap/8

Comment: we'll surely help you, if you can show us what you have done so far..

Comment: Sorry. I have added some code and an image to the topic.

Comment: try giving `border-bottom` for `nbottomitem:last-child` in your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `last-child` pseudo class for that.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   last child element of its parent.

So, Add this to your CSS

```
nbottomitem:last-child{
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```